# Borders to cells on the same line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script to create cell borders when they are not empty:

```
function checkRange2(ss) {
var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = classeur.getActiveSheet(); 

var range = ss.getRange("B5:B100");

range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
var values = range.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (values[i][j] !== "") {
      range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
      .setBackground('#FECB8D');
    }
  }
 }
}
```

I wish that when the cell, B5 for example, contains a text, the range B5: E5 is with borders. And others lines too. Is it possible?

Cordially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modifications? I don't know whether I could understand what you want to do. If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify them.

In this modified script, at first, it retrieves the values of `B5:E100`. When strings are included in column B, the borders are given to cells from column B to column E for the row. For example, when a cell B5 has strings, the cells of "B5:E5" is surrounded by the borders.

#### Modification points :

- When the column B is evaluated for the values retrieved from the range of `B5:B100`, it can be done as `if (values[i][0]) {` using one time of "for loop".

  - In this modified script, the range of `B5:E100` is used. The values retrieved this range can be also evaluated by `if (values[i][0]) {`.
- When you want to use the borders for the range of `B5:E5`, you can achieve this using `range.setBorder()`.

  - At the script, the range is defined using the a1Notation obtained by adding `offsetRow`.

#### Modified sample :

```
function checkRange2(ss) {
  var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = classeur.getActiveSheet(); 
  var range = ss.getRange("B5:E100"); // Modified
  range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var offsetRow = range.getRowIndex(); // Added
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0]) { // Modified
      ss.getRange("B" + (i + offsetRow) + ":E" + (i + offsetRow)).setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null) // Modified
      .setBackground('#FECB8D');
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note :

- If you want to give the borders to all cells, please use `.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, null)`.

  - In your case, the borders are given to one row. So the last parameter of `setBorder()` can use `null`.

#### Reference :

- [setBorder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbordertop-left-bottom-right-vertical-horizontal)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike,
your script works fine, that I wanted, however, I put a trigger to perform the script after a change, but it does not work :(

Do you know where it may come from?

Cordially.

Comment: @william I'm sorry for the inconvenience for being not enough my answer. Can I ask you the detail about the trigger? Do you want to use this sample script using the trigger of ``onEdit()``? If it's so, you can use it by installing ``checkRange2()`` as a trigger for Edit.

Comment: you have nothing to do with it :) I used a trigger to the function checkRange2 "from the spreadsheet", "after a change". This one does not work. On the other hand, you talk about onEdit (), I do not have it in the script.

Comment: @william In my environment, for the function "checkRange2()", when a trigger with "From spreadsheet" and "On change" (Is "after a change" you say "On change"?) is installed, it works fine. When the script didn't work, can you show us the log of Execution transcript? You can see "Execution transcript" at View -> Execution transcript on your script editor. If errors occur, you can see them.

Comment: amazing, I just created a new file, and there, it works properly :)
I still have a small question decidedly ^^.
If I delete the text in the cell, I have the edges that disappear, but not the color of the cell, would you have an idea?

Cordially.

Comment: @william  I'm relieved to hear that. How about modifying from ``.setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null)`` to ``.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, null)``? Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: By changing this adds a vertical inner border?
I would like the color of the cellel to be removed as soon as I delete the text on the line. Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: @william I'm sorry for the inconvenience. You can add the inner borders using .setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, null) instead of .setBorder(true, true, true, true, null, null). About the color of cells, I heard this for the first time. So can I ask you about the detail information what you want to do?

Comment: no worries, for the color, I will go through a "conditional formatting", it will be easier to implement :)
Thank you for your help and patience @Tanaike

Comment: @william Thank you, too.